# AWS CloudWatch alarm: Trigger when RDS instance is available but not used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I would like to create a CloudWatch alarm that sends an email when I forgot to delete my RDS instance after use. So I only want an alarm that triggers when the RDS instance is available. My initial approach is the following:

Create an alarm based on "CPUUtilization" and have it trigger when the utilization has on average been between 0 and 1 percent for about 1 or 2 hours.

However, until now I can only state 1 constraint. What I mean is that I can have the alarm trigger when the utilization is below 1 percent for about 1 or 2 hours. But this means that it will also trigger when the instance has been deleted.

Can anyone help me figuring out how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you stop your RDS instance, it will stop publishing metrics. Your alarm will go into INSUFFICIENT_DATA state, so your ALARM actions won't be executed.

More about CloudWatch Alarms here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However, if I have the following alarm:

If the maximum of DatabaseConnections < 1 for 2 consecutive periods of 1 hour, then send an email.

This sends an email even after I stop my RDS instance. 3 Hours after my last connection. Is it possible to add an extra constraint like:

If the maximum of DatabaseConnections < 1 for 2 consecutive periods of 1 hour AND the instance is still available, then send an email.